# VueJS - Difference between $emit and $listeners

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's take the following scenario where `WelcomePage` (parent) uses `LoginForm` (children) with a custom event `@submit`:

```html
// WelcomePage.vue
<LoginForm @submit="handleLogin">Login<Button>
```

Then, the component `LoginForm` has the following code:

```html
// LoginForm
<form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit"> ... </form>
```

```js
handleSubmit() {
  // do some stuff...

  // following Vue docs to create custom events.
  this.$emit('submit', 'some_data')

  // OR... we can also use $listeners.
  this.$listeners.submit('some_data')

  // do other stuf...
}
```

Is there any con of using  `this.$listeners.submit()` instead of `this.$emit('submit')`?

One advantage of using `this.$listeners` is it can be used with `await`, which [is a limitation of $emit](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/do-something-after-emit-has-finished-successful/10663/3) that force us to use the `done()` callback approach. And it's useful when we wanna update some state (this.isLoading) after the custom event is finished.

**Using $emit with callback:**

```js
// LoginForm.vue
async handleSubmit() {
  this.isLoading = true

  this.$emit('submit', 'some_data', () => {
    this.isLoading = false
  })

}

// WelcomePage.vue
async handleLogin(data, done) {
  // await for stuff related to "data"...

  done();
}
```

**Using $listeners with await:**

```js
// LoginForm.vue
async handleSubmit() {
  this.isLoading = true

  await this.$listeners.submit('some_data') // no need to use done callback

  this.isLoading = false
}
```

So, my question is: Is it okay to use `this.$listeners`? What's the purpose / advantage of `this.$emit`?

---

**UPDATE:**

Passing a prop `isLoading` from the parent to the children would be the first (obvious) option, instead of using `$emit`.

But that would require to set and update `this.isLoading = true | false` on `handleSubmit` every time we use the children component (and it's used a lot). So I'm looking for a solution where the parent doesn't need to worry about `isLoading` when `@submit` gets called.

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. Why would you want an async emit?

Comment: @SølveTornøe 

A concrete example: `LoginForm` needs to display a "loading state" while `WelcomePage` is handling the submit (async). When it's done, `LoginForm` needs to clean up the loading state.

Comment: I think the usual "goto" in that case would be an additional emit `loading`. Then you emit loading=true before the async function, and loading=false after.

Comment: I misunderstood your answer. What you actually would like to do is to provide a loading prop to `LoginForm`. Once the parent gets the emit `some_data`, it will set loading to true, and back to false once it is done.

Comment: Yes, using a prop + data, was my first solution, but it's a scenario (this loading state) that we do a lot across the app. I was looking for a cleaner approach. You can see the "real world challenge" here: https://github.com/okTurtles/group-income-simple/pull/854#discussion_r387399828

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209116/discussion-between-solve-tornoe-and-sandrina-p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it is that `$emit` helps you keep the FLUX architecture.
You can easily see the data flow, it helps you debug.

While using `$listeners` on the other hand is considered as a bad practice. It can be done but it can break one way data flow. The same is with a `$root`, you still have access to it, but that doesn't mean you should be using (modifing) it ;-)

Still, what to use as always depends on a context and your need. Just be careful, once broken one way data flow is very hard to debug.

---

**Edit after comment**: This is just my point of view on it.

When using `props` and `$emit` as recommended way for communication between components. You have a clear data flow. Plus Vue dev-tools helps you track every `$emit`, so you know exactly what happend step by step.

When using "collbackFunc" as a `props` and call this callback in a child component that will still work. And that is still a good way to go. The downside of it is that it is not a recommended usage.

Imagin you pass that "callbackFunc" to many childs components. When something goes wrong it is very hard to track from where it was fired.

The same applies to calling directly method on `$listeners`. Suddenly your state is changed, and you don't know exactly from where. Which and when component has fired it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you give me an example of where `$listeners` can break the flow? And how is it's harder to debug compared to `$emit`?

Comment: @sandrina-p I have updated my answer. Still this is just my point of view ;-)

Comment: @sandrina-p let me know if you still want to see the automatic loader on actions I have mentioned yesterday in the chat-room.

Comment: In the project, we decided to keep the `$listeners` approach. It's what works the best for our case and we documented it explaining the pros/cons, to help avoid any unexpected breaking change in the future. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Using props instead of callbacks from $emit

```js
const LoginForm = {
  name: 'Login-Form',
  props: {
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    }
  },
  template: `
    <button :disabled="loading" @click="$emit('some_data')">
      <template v-if="loading">Logging you in</template>
      <template v-else>login</template>
    </button>
  `,
};


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    LoginForm,
  },
  data() {
    return {
        loadingLoginForm: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleSubmit() {
      // Set loading state before async
      this.loadingLoginForm = true;
      
      // Some async shish
      setTimeout(() => this.loadingLoginForm = false, 1500)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <login-Form :loading="loadingLoginForm" @some_data="handleSubmit" />
</div>
```